KeyError: tail_type when using llm_transformer.convert_to_graph()
I am using the function llm_transformer.convert_to_graph() to create graph documents from pdf_texts and upload them to my neo4j database.
Sometimes I get a KeyError:

KeyError: 'tail_type’

or

KeyError: 'tail’”.

This doesn’t happen always (typically with the longer pdfs). Any ideas where this could be coming from and what I can do to fix it?
# Extract text from PDF
pdf_text = extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path)
  
# Create a Document object
document_pdf = [Document(page_content=pdf_text)]

llm_transformer = LLMGraphTransformer(llm=llm)

# Create a GraphDocument object
graph_documents = llm_transformer.convert_to_graph_documents(document_pdf)


Can you give us examples of pdf text that fails?  It will be hard for us to debug it without an example. Thanks.

For example: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14f157MPi67k3-4mifaMjcOdk3NyntjMN?usp=sharing
In the four files here, it works on all of them except for example #3 "Copy of FundingCall_Ex3.pdf"
